# MySQL I can't recalculate Danish currency string column to Swedish currency value (integer)

Tags: mysql

I have a column in a MySQL table that lists price values in Danish DKK like below

```
+------------+
| price      |
+------------+
| 299.95 DKK |
| 149.00 DKK |
| etc...     |
```

I now want to convert this to an integer value and recalculate it to Swedish Krona (1 DKK = 1.4). So I have tried the following:

```
UPDATE my_table SET price = ROUND(CONVERT(price, SIGNED) * 1.4) WHERE price LIKE "%DKK%"
```

However... This throws an error in MySQL:  *#1292 - Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '299.95 DKK'*

I have tried to enter

```
SELECT ROUND(CONVERT("299.95 DKK", SIGNED) * 1.4)
```

which returns the value `419` as expected...

But why do I receive the error? What's wrong with my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a warning when you do the select that is being suppressed but the SQL mode is strict and doesn't allow for the update to go through.  You can override that by using `ignore`

```
update ignore test set price = ROUND(CONVERT(price, SIGNED) * 1.4) where price LIKE "%DKK%";
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kyuDVuXov8aDt4EbsWTWHJ/0)